# Usage details of ahostsv4 in linux

Tags: linux, networking, hosts, getent

There is a term called `ahostsv4` in the Linux documentation of `man getent`. What is the usage of it?

Comment: Do you mean `ahostsv4`, as found in `man getent`? You already know it relates to `getent`, based on your usage of the tag.

Comment: Yes. I'm new to the Linux environment. I need to know why we use ahostsv4 with getent. Because man page description is not clear to me.